# C# Handling two buttons within the DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm currently developing a C# project that displays the users' orders.

Now, being that I am new to this I'm asking you to assist me on how I could possibly access the two buttons from within the DataGridView and give them separate functions.

Where I've got at code wise:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (vHisOrd_BtnDelivered.Selected)
    {

    }
    else if (vOrdHis_Btn.Selected)
    {

    }
}
```

DataGridView Image:

[image: tsfs]

Comment: The event args passed to the click handler will have the column index and row index. If nothing else you can use these to work out which button was clicked and act upon the appropriate row

Comment: You should inspect `sender` and `e` in your debugger to see which button caused the event to fire.

Comment: Thanks Caius Jard, it's now working :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add DataGridViewButtonColumn to the datagridview and use the cellcontentclick event

Use e.ColumnIndex to determine what code to execute

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView dgv = (DataGridView)sender;

    if (dgv.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewButtonColumn &&
        e.RowIndex >= 0)
    {
        //TODO - Button Clicked - Execute Code Here
    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't really solve the problem but it did give me an idea on how I can solve it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use ColumnIndex inteads of row name

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView dgv = (DataGridView)sender;
```

`//use index in your gridView
    if (dgv.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] == 2)
    {
        //vHisOrd_BtnDelivered    
    }
    else if (dgv.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] == 3)
    {
        //vOrdHis_Btn
    }`

}